# Getting the value (Numbers) in a specific column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make jquery to total all the numbers in a specific column and output it in a  in html. Heres the code

```
var vals = new Array(), i = 0, price = 0;
$("#TextBookTB tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(5)").each(function(){
  if($.inArray(i, vals) < 0)
  {
    if($.isNumeric(vals[i]))
    {
      price = price + vals[i];
      console.log(vals[i]);
      i++;
    }
  }
});
$("#ES3P").text(price);
```

Cheers!

Edit: Table as requested. The table is echoed by PHP. Not too sure why it doesn't work out properly as i hoped it should

```
echo '<div class="container-fluid MainContent">
  <div id="TBForm" class="container-fluid MainContentF">
    <table id="TextBookTB" class="table table-dark table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">A</th>
            <th scope="col">B</th>
            <th scope="col">C</th>
            <th scope="col">D</th>
            <th scope="col">E</th>
            <th scope="col">F</th>
            <th scope="col">G</th>
            <th scope="col">H</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
'; 
LoadBooks();
echo '  </tbody>

      </table>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <form id="ES3S" action="enroll.php" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="Enrollment" value="Textbooks">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Next Step</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
';
```

Comment: `var vals = new Array()` ... vals is an empty array ... and you never add anything to it ... what do you expect the content of `vals` should be?

Comment: the value from the table.. supposedly.. I thought it was supposed to to the trick already.. apparently not...

Comment: `.each(function(){` ... looping through all the selected td's ... yet you do nothing with them inside the loop?

Comment: how do you think the array `vals` *knows* what you want it to be?

Comment: With the code i have, i think i am: Getting if value is greater than 0, if the value is numeric and if it is, it's supposed to get the value of the specific value of the row from the column... Maybe you can help me out?

Comment: how is `vals` connected to `"#TextBookTB tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(5)"` ? you never assign anything to vals - added an answer - see if it helps - though, I can't begin to explain where your code went wrong. Perhaps because I don't know jQuerey well enough

Comment: Would be much easier to help if you provide the HTML table where you are trying to retrieve the values. And just a tip, think about what JaromandaX said: what if you have 2 tables in our code, how do you expect to `vals` know from which table it should get the values? Someway you need to assing a "link" between then or `push()` values to `vals`

Comment: Added the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function fCalcPrice()
{
var price = 0;
$("#TextBookTB tr:gt(0)").each(function(){
    var radio = $(this).find("input[type='radio']");
    if(radio.is(":checked"))
    {
        var content = $(this).children().eq(4).text();
        console.log(content);
        if($.isNumeric(content)) {
            price = price + Number(content);
        }
    }
});
$("#ES3P").text(price);
}

fCalcPrice();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid MainContent">
 <div id="TBForm" class="container-fluid MainContentF">
  <table id="TextBookTB" class="table table-dark table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th scope="col">A</th>
     <th scope="col">B</th>
     <th scope="col">C</th>
     <th scope="col">D</th>
     <th scope="col">E</th>
     <th scope="col">F</th>
     <th scope="col">G</th>
     <th scope="col">H</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>A</td>
     <td>B</td>
     <td>C</td>
     <td>D</td>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>F</td>
     <td>G</td>
     <td>H <input type="radio" value="test" onchange="fCalcPrice()"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>A</td>
     <td>B</td>
     <td>C</td>
     <td>D</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>F</td>
     <td>G</td>
     <td>H <input type="radio" value="test" onchange="fCalcPrice()"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>A</td>
     <td>B</td>
     <td>C</td>
     <td>D</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>F</td>
     <td>G</td>
     <td>H <input type="radio" value="test" onchange="fCalcPrice()"/></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="ES3P"></div>
```

Jaromanda X's snippet seems to work fine to me using the jQuery each function, but only when changing the $(td) to $(this), included a runnable snippet.

EDIT: Updated to only add rows to the total that contain buttons
EDIT #2: Updated to only add rows which contain ticked radio boxes

Comment: This worked.. thanks James.. one question tho.. how should i add a validation where if a button is on the same row... Its the only time it counts? Apologies.. i am really bad at javascript. Thank you tho!

Comment: @DeathKing what do you mean by "the only time it counts"? As in, it'll only add the row to the total if the row has a button?

Comment: If the radio ticked yes :)

Comment: Wait, you said button.. what exactly do you want? Does each row have a radio button? Can you select multiple radio buttons and you just want to add the rows that have ticked radio buttons?

Comment: Yes! Thats it! Apologies.. :)

Comment: There, edited. If you want anything more complicated then that I'd suggest asking it as a new question.

Comment: Awesome! Worked well.. Now i just have to figure out how it works.. lol

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like

```
var price = 0;
$("#TextBookTB tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(5)").each(function(td){
    var content = $(td).text();
    if($.isNumeric(content)) {
      price = price + Number(content);
    }
});
$("#ES3P").text(price);
```

Comment: yep this is it but it does not seem to give me any values... mmmm

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in document.ready, something like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var price = 0;
 $("#TextBookTB tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(5)").each(function(td){
   var content = $(td).text();
   if($.isNumeric(content)) {
     price = price + Number(content);
    }
   });
   $("#ES3P").text(price);
})
```